# Is there any way to merge 2 folders so that the newer text replace the old?

Tags: merge

Say I have 2 folders.

They hold similar files.

I want to merge folders. I want to do it in such a way that the newer files replace the old.

I don't know which folders are older.

How to do so?

It probably happen because the same thing backed up several times. After it's moved several time the dates are all the same

Comment: Beyond Compare?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to sync both ways, using a Windows utility such as
[robocopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy).

Execute the two commands :

```
robocopy path1 path2 /e /z
robocopy path2 path1 /e /z
```

After this is done, both folders should be up-to-date.
Taking a backup is always recommended.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/936448/robocopy-overwrite-all-files-unless-file-in-destination-is-newer

Answer (score 0):

rsync can do that.

Since you have a mix of newer files in both folders, it sounds like it's `--update` option is what you want, it would "skip files that are newer on the receiver". So a command something like this (`-a` is it's archive mode), and ran again with the paths reversed, to get the new files from dir2 into dir1:

```
rsync -a --update /dir1/ /dir2
rsync -a --update /dir2/ /dir1
```

It has a lot of options, and some unexpected quirks, like the one below. The `-n, --dry-run` option could be useful to see what will happen before actually doing anything.

> You can think of a trailing / on a source as meaning
> "copy the contents of this directory" as opposed to "copy the directory by name", but  in
> both  cases  the attributes of the containing directory are transferred to the containing
> directory on the destination.  In other words, each of the following commands copies  the
> files in the same way, including their setting of the attributes of /dest/foo:

> ```
> rsync -av /src/foo /dest
> rsync -av /src/foo/ /dest/foo
> ```

---

You haven't mentioned what OS you're using, but rsync is available for Linux, WSL ("Linux on windows"), and windows. A very brief search found this How to Use Rsync in Windows 10 | Tutorial and Alternative" https://www.ubackup.com/windows-10/rsync-windows-10-1021.html